# Given a book node nid, programmatically get all child node nids

Tags: 8

I use the D8 Book module to create books with chapters. Works great.

When an editor makes a certain change to a book node, I need to look at each of its chapter (child) nodes to potentially adjust a field in them.

I know how to detect the book node change in `node_presave()`. I know how to load, modify, and save a child node once I have its nid. What I don't know is how to get a complete list child node nids for the book.

I've read many posts related to this subject, but none that provide a straightforward way to programmatically get a list of child node nids given the parent book node nid. I've also looked at the Book module documentation. I assume I'm just overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the complete list of child node nids for the book:
use the [`BookOutlineStorage::loadBookChildren`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21book%21src%21BookOutlineStorage.php/function/BookOutlineStorage%3A%3AloadBookChildren/8.2.x) from the `book.outline_storage` service.
like the following:

```
/** @var \Drupal\book\BookOutlineStorageInterface $book_outline_storage */
$book_outline_storage = \Drupal::service('book.outline_storage');
$childrens  =  $book_outline_storage->loadBookChildren(NID);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @berramou! So easy, and yet nearly impossible without your help.

Comment: you are welcome @MarshallMorrise i'm glad that helps !